# Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Водопады расположены на территории сразу двух стран - США и Канады.

Answer (score 2):

Тире поставлено правильно, так как США и КАНАДЫ - приложения, которые стоят в конце предложения и имеют пояснительное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Время от времени аист приносил в своём длинном клюве еду – маленького ужа или лягушку с четырьмя растопыренными лапами (два однородных распространённых приложения стоят после определяемого слова – имени нарицательного; выделяются с помощью тире, так как имеют пояснительное значение: перед ними можно вставить а именно)